# Is it good practice to access concrete class type from abstract class method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Scenario:**
I have an abstract class method to call different database stored procedures based on a property value which is set by concrete class construction. A particular concrete class needs to send an extra parameter to the stored procedure.

**Question:**
Is it good practice to access concrete class type from the abstract class method and send extra parameter to the database stored procedure if the concrete class is particular type?
Below is code snippet: Please suggest if I am doing it wrong.

```
Public MustInherit Class dbBaseCustomField

  Protected _TableName as string

  Public Sub Save(conn as string, customField as CustomField)
   lSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   lSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = ApplicationGlobals.cCommandTimeout       
   lSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentItemId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = piParentItemId
   lSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CFChk" , SqlDbType.Int).Value = customField.Value
   If (Me.GetType() Is GetType(MemberCustomField)) Then
    lSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@AddSyncTrigger ", SqlDbType.Int).Value =    customField.AddSyncTrigger
   End If

   lSqlConnection.Open()
   lSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   lSqlConnection.Close()

  End Sub
End Class

Public Class MemberCustomField
  Inherits dbBaseCustomField

  Sub New()
    _TableName = "MemberCustomField"
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class LocationCustomField
  Inherits dbBaseCustomField

  Sub New()
    _TableName = "LocationCustomField"
  End Sub

End Class
```

NOTE: I used VB code and tagged C# as there are more c# developers and question will reach many people. Concept is same whether it is vb.net or c#

Comment: You have tagged this as C#, but it is VB.

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong, and it is a bad practice. Are you ready to adjust base class every time new subclass emerges? What about sub-subclass? What if someone else wants to subclass your base class? If subclass needs to do something specific, just give it enough flexibility to do so in the base class. For instance, you could have protected collection of params, to which subclasses could add stuff. Or use template method pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to define a protected, abstract, get-only property in your base class that returns a bool indicating whether the class needs the extra parameter.  Or if it will only be true in rare cases, you could provide a default implementation in the base class that returns false.  Override the getter in `MemberCustomField` to return true.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you already know it's bad practice. 
Perhaps the question is, what should be done instead?

If you want to add extra parameters, use a virtual/abstract method which returns those parameters:

```
    Public Overridable Function ExtraParameters() as List(Of SqlParameters) 

        // your derived classes can return the extra parameters, if any
        Return New List(Of SqlParameter)
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do if you inherit from your base class and forget to set the name?

You might want to either check `_TableName` has been set and throw an exception or add the table name as a parameter to the save method.